# How does this Sudoku Solver Work?

Tags: java, algorithm

I've found some code that solves a sudoku puzzle, but I only understand part of it.

```
static boolean solve(int i, int j, int[][] cells) {
    if (i == 9) {
        i = 0;
        if (++j == 9)
            return true;
    }
    if (cells[i][j] != 0)  // skip filled cells
        return solve(i+1,j,cells);

    for (int val = 1; val <= 9; ++val) {
        if (legal(i,j,val,cells)) {
            cells[i][j] = val;
            if (solve(i+1,j,cells))
                return true;
        }
    }
    cells[i][j] = 0; // reset on backtrack
    return false;
}

static boolean legal(int i, int j, int val, int[][] cells) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k)  // row
        if (val == cells[k][j])
            return false;

    for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) // col
        if (val == cells[i][k])
            return false;

    int boxRowOffset = (i / 3)*3;
    int boxColOffset = (j / 3)*3;
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) // box
        for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m)
            if (val == cells[boxRowOffset+k][boxColOffset+m])
                return false;

    return true; // no violations, so it's legal
}
```

I understand the legal() method, it simply checks for duplicates which is not permitted. What is not so clear is how the recursion in solve() is doing its job.

Could anyone provide insight on how that part works. I really want to understand it so I can implement one myself.

Thanks

Comment: You should find [this](http://www.norvig.com/sudoku.html) extremely interesting - even if it is the wrong language :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm works using recursion and backtracking, basically it "brute forces" the sudoku until it finds a correct answer.

It will loop through the numbers 1 - 9 until it finds a number that is legal for that cell at the moment. The algorithm will backtrack (i.e. reset the numbers) the numbers when they are not in a valid combination. It will do each column and row until it solves the entire puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I knew what I meant but wrote it poorly :) I'll update

Answer (score 1):

It tries each insertion which is legal at the moment.
Of course, only one of those will result in the true solution, so it checks them for true or false.

The incorrect tries will hit a dead-end somewhere and return false.

Answer (score 1):

In layman terms, `solve` does the following:

```
solve(position, field):
  for all values of all positions:
    fill current position of field with current value
    solve(neighboring position, field) # solve 'the rest'
    if field is a legal solution:
      return field
    else:
      unfill current position of field
    # the loop proceeds to next position
```